# Parkour on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As the title really - it's done outdoors, but would this more come under the sports proposal? Not that I have any specific question that I wanted to ask - just curious... :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is an interesting question. I'm inclined to say not in general, but I'll leave open the possibility that there *might* be some question about some very specific aspect that could be on-topic here, though I can't think of any off the top of my head. Parkour is more about avoiding/surmounting man-made obstacles than interacting with nature.

I think our rule-of-thumb should be that we take sports where nature plays an integral role - sailing requires interacting with wind, skiing snow, mountaineering and climbing rock, etc. Parkour strongly tends toward interaction with man-made obstacles.

I've talked with the Sports and F&N mods, and I think we should direct parkour questions to Fitness.SE. Most, if not all, aspects (that are otherwise appropriate for SE) should find a good home there.

Sports is unlikely to take most parkour questions, they were pushing toward "competitive" sports (much to the chagrin of many who had committed to other non-competitive proposals, like running, that were rolled into sports).